# What the script to change the password should be in php?

Tags: php, change-password

```
<form action="final_change_pwd.php" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="20">
                <tr>
                    <td> Current Password: </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="txtoldpwd" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> New Password: </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="txtnewpwd" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Confirm Password: </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="txtnewpwd" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

// This is the form I have and I need a script to figure out what the process of changing password should be...!
// Anyone there to help me???

Comment: We will not write your page for you.  Please ask a specific question.

Comment: I asked a process not the whole script...!  I need a path to proceed on...!

Comment: Be a bit more specific? This doesn't tell us anything. Do you want a user of a site to change their password? You mean you want a process outline of changing the password, or a ready made script?Are you using a database? Etc...

Comment: I need an outline...!  A user of a site changes the password which is stored in a database...!

Comment: Use pseudo code or talk the OP through it; we don't have to be rude about it. If you "won't write the page" for them, then either put up (with some explanation of what should be done, in text/pseudo code/actual code), or shut up (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

Fix the name of the input field for Confirm Password as it is the same as New Password. Also send the user ID along in the form as a hidden field.

Process would be to:

check the userid and current password. if they match:
check if new password matches the conformation. 
then save it to db.

the process itself is not the hard part though, securing everything is. try to encrypt values before you post it (javascripts available that do this), and salt them afterwards. check if the new password meets possible password requirements (also javascript, before you post it) like at least 6 chars long, has a number in it etc, and even checking if the new password and conformation match can be done before you post anything using javascript.

As advice though, maybe you should consider not doing this yourself at all, because it will never be as secure as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources online like [this site](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_change_password.php) that can walk you through what you need to do:  http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_change_password.php